# I've disistallated eclipse and now i can't reinstall adt plugin for android

Tags: android, eclipse

I've disistallated eclipse and now i can't reinstall adt plugin for android development it says
i'm on mac yosemite

i do as explained here
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.6.1720515 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.php 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Common Eclipse Runtime 3.6.0.v20100503 (org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.6.0.v20100503)
    Common Eclipse Runtime 3.6.100.v20120522-1841 (org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.6.100.v20120522-1841)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.6.1720515 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
    To: org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.php 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.php.feature.feature.group [1.3.2.20110218-0812]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Core Runtime 3.8.0.v20120912-155025 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0.v20120912-155025)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.100,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP PHP Feature 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (org.eclipse.epp.package.php.feature.feature.group 1.3.2.20110218-0812)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.0.v20100503]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.0.v20100503]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.0.v20100503]

i don'understand what is this conflict i have also jboss installed and i've deleter eclipse luna, could you help me? thanks